# ¿Como reemplazar valores desde un dataframe a otro?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

Tengo dos dataframe, en donde uno posee mucha información y una de sus columnas es Codigo_Comuna, y tengo otro dataframe con todos los codigos de comuna y el nombre de la comuna asociado a ese código. Lo que debo hacer es que en mi primera tabla, reemplazar el código comuna, por el nombre de la comuna sacado desde el otro dataframe.
Espero puedan ayudarme.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi primera imagen es mi DATAFRAME 1, en donde en la columna Comuna, el valor en numero, debo reemplazarlo con el nombre del segundo dataframe.

Comment: Añade el codigo que has utilizado para que sea mas facil replicar y ayudarte.

Comment: Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español, mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funciona el sitio y de paso obtener tu primera medalla. Por favor siempre coloca tu código y lo que hayas intentado. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Estás tratando de unir dos frames con base en sus keys (columnas `comuna` y `Codigo`). Podrías utilizar `merge`:

```
import pandas as pd

#Primer DataFrame df1
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'comuna':range(5), 'columna_1':[10,23,24,1,2], 'columna_2':list('abcde')}, index=range(5))

#Segundo DataFrame df2
df2 = pd.DataFrame ({'Codigo':range(5), 'nombre_comuna':['com1','com2','com3','com4','com5']}, index=range(5))

dfResult = df1.merge(df2, left_on='comuna', right_on='Codigo', how='inner')
```

df1 :

```
     comuna  columna_1 columna_2
0       0       10        a
1       1       23        b
2       2       24        c
3       3        1        d
4       4        2        e
```

df2:

```
    Codigo  nombre_comuna
0       0       com1
1       1       com2
2       2       com3
3       3       com4
4       4       com5
```

dfResult:

```
    comuna  columna_1 columna_2  Codigo  nombre_comuna
0      0       10        a         0         com1
1      1       23        b         1         com2
2      2       24        c         2         com3
3      3        1        d         3         com4
4      4        2        e         4         com5
```

El frame dfResult contendrá la unión de ambos frames, así que podrías excluir las columnas `Codigo` y `comuna`, y quedarte con `nombre_comuna` pero solamente cuando vayas a presentar los datos. En back podrías trabajar sobre dfResult directamente ya que contiene los códigos (keys).

Es importante ver qué quieres realizar cuando no se encuentre el código en el segundo frame (el tipo de join a utilizar). Para ello, tendrías que modificar el parámetro `how` con `left`, `right`, `outer` ó `inner`. [Aquí](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) puedes encontrar más al respecto del método `merge`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la funcio `loc` de `pandas.DataFrame` para obtener los valores de un dataframe que cumplan con una condicion especifica.

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame({"codigo":[101,102,103,104],"comuna":["a","b","c","d"]})
y = pd.DataFrame({"comuna":[101,102,103,104],"manzana":[2,2,2,2],"predio":[3,2,1,4]})
y["comuna"] = x.loc[x["codigo"]==y["comuna"],"comuna"]
print(y)
```

Lo que hace ese codigo es primero crear los dataframe, despues de eso obtiene del dataframe a modificar la columna especifica y esta la iguala a un valor obtenido con `df.loc`

### Edicion

Puedes hacer uso de la libreria `numpy` y la funcion `np.where` para remplazar los objetos, nada mas modificando el codigo, este funciona sin importar el orden

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x = pd.DataFrame({"codigo":[101,102,103,104],"comuna":["a","b","c","d"]})
y = pd.DataFrame({"comuna":[103,102,101,104],"manzana":[2,2,2,2],"predio":[3,2,1,4]})

for i in y["comuna"]:
  y['comuna'] = np.where((y.comuna == i),x.loc[(x["codigo"] == i),"comuna"],y.comuna)
print(y)
```